# Three states MaterialDesign Toggle Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, togglebutton

I'm using MaterialDesign library and I have a toggle button which currently has only two states, 1 for Edge browser and other for Chrome with PackIcons representing each browser.

How can I add a third state with a third PackIcon image i.e. IE11, so I have a choice of three states i.e.: Edge, Chrome and IE11?

```
<ToggleButton Foreground="DodgerBlue" IsThreeState="True" Margin="2" 
                          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionToggleButton}"
                          ToolTip="Chcck this out!" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=xxxxxxxxxxxxx, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <ToggleButton.Content>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="MicrosoftEdge" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                </ToggleButton.Content>

                <materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent >
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="GoogleChrome" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Foreground="Red"/>
                </materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent>

            </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: `ToggleButton` has 2 states defined by value of `IsChecked`. You can take a normal `Button` and use e.g. `enum` to store state and retrieve corresponding icon.

Comment: @Thomas Do you want to have a button that changes the icon and the bound value when clicked, e.g. _Edge_ - Click - _Chrome_ - Click - _IE11_ - click - _Edge_ - ...? Is the button bound to any command or action that it should ivoke when clicked or is it just for _selecting_ the browser?

Comment: @thatguy That's the idea. I would like to fire up selected browser based on the ToggleButton state. I have experimented with different solutions but postponed until third state is solved in xaml.

Comment: @Thomas How about a simple `ComboBox` for selecting the browser?

Comment: @thatguy I'm updating the app which already have two states toggle buttons, don't want to confuse the users by changing the design to combo now. I though there will be an easy solution to add a third state to the toggle button.

Comment: @thatguy I think I may have to use combo perhaps, I really like that toggle btns though :-). Thanks for help everyone.